# Reference a fragment from another activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, broadcastreceiver

I have a activity which contains two fragments which are two instance of one class fragment. These fragments have listview which loads data from the server and fetches more data when the last item in list appears.  Clicking on fragment list item starts another activity displaying the items in a viewpager. The viewpager downloads more data as the user swipes and update the current page number . When the page number is updated this information has to be given back to the fragment in the starting activity.

What would be the best approach to do this ?

- Broadcast receiver
- Getting fragment reference from starting activity and calling updatePageNumber() method 
  ?

Answer (score 1):

You're underestimating the power of static variables. They're not that bad as most people think.

That being out of the way, the "proper" way would be to deliver the data back via setResult, and catching it on the first activity via onActivityResult. If you want to set the result from the second activity's fragment, do `getActivity().setResult`

Comment: in my case I have two instance of the fragment So static variables fail.